# Disable angular trim on directive attribute

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

Currently writing a directive, and need to pass space as character to it.
like:

`<my-directive exclude-chars=" abc"/>`

Turns out that angular removes the leading space; but I want it preserved. 
Any way of doing that?

EDIT: I'm passing the directive parameter as a string (using @, not as a variable, using =)

Comment: You are showing it on HTML view ? Can you share youre template where you use exclude-chars ?

Comment: Maybe just wrap your chars with quotes so it would be a string?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I would do one of:

1. Wrap the attribute in `{{'` and `'}}`:

   ```
   <my-directive exclude-chars="{{' abc'}}"></my-directive>
   ```

   and access the string  `abc`, including the space, using `attrs.excludeChars` in the link function of the directive

   ```
   link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
     var excludeChars = attrs.excludeChars;
   }
   ```
2. Wrap the attribute in `'` and `'`:

   ```
   <my-directive exclude-chars="' abc'"></my-directive>
   ```

   and then pass the value through `$eval` to get to the string including the space:

   ```
   link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
     var excludeChars = scope.$eval(attrs.excludeChars);
   }
   ```

Note: directly accessing the attribute via the jQuery/jQlite `attr` function is ever so slightly not friendly to Angular supporting different formats of directives/attributes via [normalization](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive#normalization), and forces the users to the directive to use the one you access via `attr`.

---

BTW: Custom HTML elements should have the closing tag explicitly in the template. If you don't, I've found the DOM that the browser uses often isn't quite what is expected

Comment: Solution 1 worked perfectly. DIdn't thought of it, thanks! RE BTW: I know, I was too lazy to type the end tag.

Comment: 'Wrap the attribute in {{' and '}}'. I think I need a break because I don't event think of that solution. You save my night, thanks !

Answer (score 1):

One of the most simple solution is to use jqlite `attr` function like the code below.

In your directive code.

```
link: function(scope, element, attrs){
    console.log('>'+element.attr("exclude-chars"));
}
```

[Demo jsfiddle is here.](https://jsfiddle.net/yazaki/2qa4encg/)

Comment: this would work also, but it's not "the angular way". As a fun fact, if you attempt `attrs.excludeChars`, you would still have the space stripped.